# CSS form[action] not working with Query Strings

Tags: css, css-selectors

Hi all having a few problems with my CSS
I am trying to highlight a link on the navigation based on the page the user is on.

I have this style which works as I would like it to do, but when I pass a query-string into pcisHPprofile.aspx the CSS is not working. Does anyone know how i can get this style to work with query-strings?

```
 body form[action="pcisHPprofile.aspx"] #btnuser

{
    padding: 18px 4px 5px 4px;
    background-image: url(../images/tabbluleft.gif) ;
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    color: #fff;

}



<div id="nav" class="nav" >

      <ul>
       <li id="tab1">
       <a id="btnsession" href="pcissessionlist.aspx" > <span >Session</span></a>
         </li>
          <li id="tab2">
              <a id="btnsystem" href="pcissystemsettings.aspx" > <span >System Settings</span></a>
            </li>
          <li id="tab3">
          </li>
          <li id="tab4">
                            <a id="btnuser" href="pcisuserlist.aspx" > <span >User Logins</span></a>
              </li>
          <li id="tab5">
                                          <a id="btninterpreter" href="pcisinterpreterlist.aspx" > <span >Interpreter Profile</span></a>

              </li>
       <li id="tab6"><asp:LinkButton ID="btnreports" runat="server" Visible="false" cssid="cssreports" PostBackUrl="#"><span>Reports</span></asp:LinkButton></li>
      </ul> 

    </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that the #btnuser ARE some buttonS inside the some forms, where one of the forms have action="pcisHPprofile.aspx"?

If that is correct, then your error is the fact that you have many buttons with the same id attirbute id="btnuser". The ID attibute MUST be uniqe on the page. change the id="btnuser" to class="btnuser" on the buttons and your selector from:

```
body form[action="pcisHPprofile.aspx"] #btnuser {
}
```

to

```
body form[action="pcisHPprofile.aspx"] .btnuser {
}
```

Then it should work.

In the first form it might work only if the FIRST button with id="btnuser" is actually inside the form with action="pcisHPprofile.aspx". If it is inside any other form, then it will not work.

Best regards, 
SWilk

UPDATE:

After OP updated the question, I think that this form of selector should work:

```
body form[action^="pcisHPprofile.aspx"] #btnuser {
...
}
```

It would a element with id=btnuser inside a form, which action **begins with** "pcisHPprofile.aspx". It would not matter if the acutal action attibute contain only "pcisHPprofile.aspx" or "pcisHPprofile.aspx?any-parameters&and=some-values".

Best regards,
SWilk

Comment: its an a href and everyone has a unique ID
 <a id="btnuser" href="pcisuserlist.aspx" > <span >User Logins</span></a>

 <a id="btninterpreter" href="pcisinterpreterlist.aspx" > <span >Interpreter Profile</span></a>

Comment: The form element misleaded me. If so, then I do not see any other reason why this should not work. If you can provide an example of your html code, then it might be easier to spot the problem.

Comment: I have edited the Question. It all works fine until pcisHPprofile.aspx is pcisHPprofile.aspx?userID=5

Comment: have you tried action^="url" instead of action="url"? 
body form[action^="pcisHPprofile.aspx"] #btnuser {} 

This would match a form with any action that starts with pcisHPprofile.aspx

Comment: better than what I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

Using action attribute for styling is a bad practice. Just give your form a name, class or ID like <form class="pcisHPprofile" action="pcisHPprofile.aspx"> and then apply CSS style to that name/class/id.

```
form.pcisHPprofile { 
     padding: ...
```

Comment: That sounds as if it should work. Only problem is that I am using master pages.

Answer (score 0):

Found a working solution. a little hacky which I am not 100% keen on but it works.

I changed the query string to look like this

```
profile.aspx?-&username=
```

from this

```
 profile.aspx?username=
```

and I changed the style to

```
Form[action|="pcisinterpreterprofile.aspx?"] #tab5


{
background-image: url(../images/tabbluright.gif);
  background-repeat:no-repeat; 

}
```

The difference is that I have changed the = to an |=.

> [att|=val]
>       Represents an element with the att attribute, its value either being
>   exactly "val" or beginning with "val"
>   immediately followed by "-" (U+002D).
>   This is primarily intended to allow
>   language subcode matches (e.g., the
>   hreflang attribute on the a element in
>   HTML) as described in RFC 3066
>   ([RFC3066]) or its successor. For lang
>   (or xml:lang) language subcode
>   matching, please see the :lang
>   pseudo-class.

by doing this the css selector works on pages with query strings. you just need to make sure the query string has at least ?- at the start. As I said at the last its not great but works.